# Getting td value returns undefined

Tags: jquery, html-table, children

I am trying to access the td value of a row above a context. I am able to get the row above with the `prev()` method and also get the children with the `children()` method, but when I append a find() with a selector onto that, I am unable to find the particular cell I am looking for.

When I log the return from `children()` I see all the table data i have in there.

Why cant I find by id? See code below.

```
$("#tblProducts tbody").on("click", "#btnSubmitUpdate", function (e) {
    var btnSaveUpdate = $(this);

    var tr = btnSaveUpdate.closest("tr");

    var trAbove = $(tr.prev()[0]);
    var desc = trAbove.children().find("#tdDescription").val();

    //desc is returning undefined
    console.log(desc);
});
```

Comment: `td` (table cell) doesn't have value (or val()) property.
use `trAbove.children().find("#tdDescription").html()` instead.

Comment: even doing that 'var desc = trAbove.children().find("#tdDescription").html();' returns undefined! @AlexKudryashev

Comment: try `$('#tdDescription', trAbove).html()`. Meanwhile, are you sure that your `td` has `id="tdDescription"` not `class="tdDescription"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use find() directly with the trAbove without using the children. This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$("#tblProducts tbody").on("click", "td", function() {
    var tdAttr = $(this).attr('class')
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find("td."+tdAttr).text())
    /*
      or $(this).text(), $(this).attr('class') or $(this).data('id')
    */
})
```

I wrote a sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/nht9nvzy/